# autochdir and NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

`autochdir` automatically sets the current working directory to the present file that the cursor is located on. I'd like to exclude `autochdir` from changing the directory if the cursor is in the NERDTree window.

For example, if the present file I'm working on is in `~/foo`, and the NERDTree window is in `~/lots/of/stuff/here`, I'd like to go to the NERDTree window and still have the current working directory set to `~/foo`.

That way, one can apply the `CD` keybind, which will set NERDTree's root tree node to `~/foo`. Otherwise, it's terribly inconvenient to manually change the root tree node in the NERDTree window by navigating to `~/foo`, and then applying the `cd` keybind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `:help autochdir`:

> This option is provided for backward compatibility with the Vim
>   released with Sun ONE Studio 4 Enterprise Edition.
>   **Note:** When this option is on some plugins may not work.

I.e. it is obsolete, inflexible and breaks plugins. I suggest you don't use it, and instead use one of the alternate, more configurable mechanisms [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file). For instance,

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &ft !~ '^nerdtree$' | silent! lcd %:p:h | endif
```

However, while this does not change the current directory when you pull up NERDTree, it will not preserve it, either. I'm not 100% sure what you mean in your last paragraph.

Comment: I wouldn't be so harsh about this very useful option. I use it with 100+ plugins without problems. You're right, however, that for this particular use case, the autocmd emulation would be beneficial (though in this primitive form, it has other shortcomings...)

Comment: @IngoKarkat: Fair enough. Personally, I'd be annoyed if `pwd` changed except by my own action, so this is obviously not well tested. :)